# Statement Based Replication and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Tags: mysql

We started using statement-based replication, and found that it breaks SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS(), and I'm looking for a work around. A comment from a bug report in 2007 suggests using `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS INTO @found_rows FROM foo`, but that doesn't seem to work. MySQL says the syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an older version of MySQL, that could be part of your problem: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

> FOUND_ROWS() is not replicated
>   reliably using statement-based
>   replication. Starting with MySQL
>   5.1.23, this function is automatically replicated using row-based
>   replication.

**Edit:** The above only works if you're in `MIXED` mode.

Also, the correct workaround syntax is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM foo;
SET @found_rows = FOUND_ROWS();
```

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` doesn't return anything, it just tells MySQL to calculate the number of found rows from the query, even if a `LIMIT` clause prevents all of them from being returned to the client.  `FOUND_ROWS()` can then be used to return the value that was temporarily stored by `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

**Edit:** The idea behind the above workaround (as documented in [MySQL bug 12092](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12092)):

> The result of FOUND_ROWS() is stored
>   into a user variable and used that
>   way instead. This will replicate
>   correctly   even under statement-based
>   replication, since it will write a
>   User_var entry to the binary log.

Comment: We're using 5.1.56, but we're not using row-based replication, so that doesn't help.

Comment: @mellowsoon If you change your syntax for the `SELECT` to what I put in my answer, does it work, or is it prevented by statement-based replication?

Comment: I don't have any reason to think it'll work. We're already using `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM foo`, followed by `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`, and that doesn't work with statement-based replication.

Comment: @mellowsoon Your question has different syntax, which is why I corrected it.  The error message you are getting (or the incorrect behavior that tells you it "doesn't work" when using the syntax in my answer would be helpful.

Comment: It works, but my db abstraction layer doesn't support multiple statements in a single query, so I didn't give this much thought. Had to change things a bit to work it all out. Thanks.